# Pod outdated failes caused by Firebase/AdMob

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I tried to find new pod-versions after the release of Swift 4.2. So I called

> pod outdated

in the terminal. According to this this kind of error message occurs:

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/AdMob":
   In Podfile:
      Firebase/AdMob

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/AdMob` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler":
In Podfile:
Firebase/AdMob was resolved to 5.8.0, which depends on
  Firebase/Core (= 5.8.0) was resolved to 5.8.0, which depends on
    FirebaseAnalytics (= 5.1.2) was resolved to 5.1.2, which depends on
      GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 5.2.0)

Specs satisfying the `GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 5.2.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

The deployment target wasn't changed and is still at 9.0. These Firebase-Pods are listed in my Podfile:

```
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
```

The current version of Firebase/AdMob is (5.8.0).I already removed all pods and installed them new. But didn't worked.

Has anyone a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `pod update`.

This was fixed today in Firebase 5.8.1. Details in this [github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1845).

Comment: Hi @Paul Beusterien, my cocoapod version is 1.6.1, I can’t update my firebase to 5.18.1 or 5.18.2 by running pod update. I facing the same issues as this post author about Firebase/AdMob. Do u know how to update my firebase version?

Comment: @Scuttlebutt 5.18.0 is the latest CocoaPods release. 5.18.1 and 5.18.2 are only to fix issues with the Carthage and zip distributions.

Comment: If `pod update` fails to get the latest releases, there is likely a hard dependency from something else in the `Podfile`. Examine the `Podfile.lock` file to get an explanation about why the specific pod versions were chosen.